# I'm having a Heroku login problem, "timed out"

Tags: python-3.x, heroku

I'm having this problem while login through my cmd and atom terminal:

[image]

Comment: "Timed out" probably means that the route or port you are trying to use is blocked. See if you are running a computer or network firewall.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't
be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the text directly into your
question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four
spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.